# Codeigniter Database Values Not Showing In View

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have encountered an issue where the data from my database is not showing in my view. As far as I'm aware, my Controller, Model and View are set up correctly. I've done this before so I know what's needed, but I can't locate my old file. I hope you guys can help?

Controller:

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Hacking Attempt: Get out of the system ..!');

class C_Live extends CI_Controller
{    

function C_Live(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('M_live');
}

public function index(){
  $query = $this->M_live->getUpgrades();
  if(isset($query)){
      $data['upgrades'] = $query;
  }
  $this->load->view('Test', $data);
 } 
}

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Hacking Attempt: Get out of the system ..!');

class M_live extends CI_Model
{
  function M_live()
  {
    parent::Model();
  }

  function getUpgrades()
  {
    $query = $this->db->get('live_client_trust_versions');
    // Produces: SELECT * FROM client_trust_versions
    return $query->num_rows() > 0  $query->result() : NULL;
  }
}
?>
```

View:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>App Server</th>
        <th>Instance Name</th>
        <th>BankStaff Server</th>
        <th>SQL Server</th>
        <th>Instance</th>
        <th>Health Roster Version</th>
        <th>Employee Online Version</th>
        <th>Roster Perform</th>
        <th>BankStaff Version</th>
        <th>SafeCare Version</th>
        <th>E-Expenses</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
if(isset($upgrades)){
//If no rows were found $upgrades will be NULL and isset() will return false. 
//Therefore, you never try to address an undefined variable.  
  foreach($upgrades as $upgrade){?>

        <tr>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->ID;?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->Client_Name?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->App_Server?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->Instance_Name?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->BankStaff_Server?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->SQL_Server;?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->Instance;?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->Health_Roster_Version;?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->Employee_Online_Version;?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->Roster_Perform_Version;?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->BankStaff_Version;?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->SafeCare_Version;?></td>
        <td><?php=$upgrade->E-Expenses;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }}?>
</table>
```

[The result I'm getting in my view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCEkz.png)

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-and-select-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-beginner-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your controller

```
class C_Live extends CI_Controller
{    

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

   $this->load->model('M_live', '', TRUE);
}


public function index(){
  $data['upgrades'] = $this->M_live->getUpgrades();
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($data['upgrades']);
  $this->load->view('Test', $data);
 } 
}
```

and model to

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Hacking Attempt: Get out of the system ..!');



      class M_live extends CI_Model
        {
          function __construct()
          {
            parent::Model();
          }

          function getUpgrades()
          {
           // $query = $this->db->get('live_client_trust_versions');
            // Produces: SELECT * FROM client_trust_versions
            //return $query->num_rows() > 0  $query->result() : NULL;
           $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('live_client_trust_versions');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result();
              return $result;
          }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I've tried what you have suggested but my table is still not showing.

Comment: I'm really sorry to be a pain, but it's still not showing the data is the view. I'm completely stumped on what it could be.

Comment: try print_r($data['upgrades']); in the controller before view load and let me know the output

Comment: nothing... I'm starting to think that it might be my controller that is buggered! It seems like it's not talking to my model or view etc.

Comment: Now run your controller and let me know the output this should work.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when running just my controller:

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_Model::Model()

Filename: models/M_live.php

Line Number: 10

Comment: Updated my answer code inside controller construct try i

Comment: Still no use, but I removed the parent::Model() from my model and I am now getting the following displaying on my when I run C_live 

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [Client_Name] => 
            [App_Server] => 
            [Instance_Name] => FIVEBP
            [BankStaff_Server] => N/A
            [SQL_Server] => UKASSQL06
            [Instance] => LIVE/PRE-PROD
            [Health_Roster_Version] => 10.5.163.14
            [Employee_Online_Version] => 10.5.1.89
         
This is the data is after, but it need to show in my view not controller

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-and-select-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-beginner-guide/

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong

```
<?php=$upgrade->ID;?>
```

either it should be

```
<?php echo $upgrade->ID;?> or  <?= $upgrade->ID;?>
```

This should help. And also

```
return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result() : NULL;
                              ^ is missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you have missed a `?` in your `return` call:

```
return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result() : NULL;
              // Missing here ^
```